# Create an Office 365 calendar with Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

**Scenario**
I work for a company that uses ServiceNow and integrates with Outlook calendars for various employees/job bookings etc.

When we take on a new employee which happens very often at the moment, I have to create them in Office 365 as you would expect, I then have to add them to various groups and then create a new calendar with that users name inside a shared mailbox.

For example > Access shared mailbox abc@example.com > Calendars > New Calendar > John Smith Appointments

I then need to give (in this example) John Smith Edit rights and another few management edit rights to that calendar so they are able to schedule appointments for John Smith.

It's a faf to do so I thought lets write a script.

What I have so far is I have a powershell script that asks for the first and last name, then it goes off and generates a user, adds them to the correct groups.

What I am struggling with is how do I **create** a calendar in the shared mailbox using Powershell.

I'm competent adding the permissions etc that's not the issue, but I can't seem to find out to create the calendar in the first place!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendars are a folder object in a mailbox, so you can get some information about existing calendars with commands like:

```
Get-MailboxFolder 'Shared Mailbox:\Calendars\John Smith Appointments'
Get-MailboxCalendarFolder 'Shared Mailbox:\Calendars\John Smith Appointments'
```

This can be useful to compare to your newly created calendars, and you specifically want to make sure the parent folder has `FolderClass : IPF.Appointment` to be inherited by the new calendar.

To actually make a new one, it's simply:

```
New-MailboxFolder -Name 'John Doe Appointments' -Parent 'Shared Mailbox:\Calendars'
```

This creates a new calendar with a lot of defaults that you can add sharing and/or publishing settings to.